# Perl size of first recieving packet(s)

Tags: perl, libpcap, tcpdump

I wonder how I can get the size of the first receiving packets from the server using Perl. I have simple pieces of code downloaded from different examples for NET::PCAP. But I do not know how can I get the size of the first packet out of it.

Any help, or good link is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? *(Just modifying the example from the Synopsis on the [Net::PCAP](http://search.cpan.org/~saper/Net-Pcap-0.16/Pcap.pm) page.)*

```
use Net::Pcap;

my $err = '';
my $size = 0;
my $dev = pcap_lookupdev(\$err);  # find a device
my $pcap = pcap_open_live($dev, 1024, 1, 0, \$err);
my $loop_func = sub { my($user_data, $header, $packet) = @_; 
                      $size = $header->{len}; };
pcap_loop($pcap, 1, $loop_func, "just for the demo");
pcap_close($pcap);
print $size," bytes\n";
```